# Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs

Tags: linux, oracle-linux

I have ORACLE LINUX server and electricity cut off after start the server I got this error :

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)
```

I saw some questions they said to update the GRUB file and change root path , but how can I open the terminal and where the file path location

[image]

this is screen shot the error
please I need your help this is production system server .
thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this worked before, and the power outage is really to blame, then you probably lost a hard drive.

It might, however, also be the effect of changing something about GRUB from the running Oracle Linux, and then deferring the reboot until electricity forced you to.

Either way, you will want to boot a separate Linux system, and check the state of your storage.

Luckily, you're on a server (a HP ProLiant BL460c, to be precise), which has a dedicated management network port. You can just log in to the board management controller (BMC), it's called "integrated lights-out management" (iLO) at HP, and you can upload an image of a temporary OS to boot, and it will show you what's on the screen remotely; you don't have to copy e.g. a current Oracle installer image to an USB drive and run to the server and stand in front of it. [Here's the link to the manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00553302.pdf).

Generally though, I'd say this is a blade server, so you're in a high-density computing environment. That means someone hopefully has saved the image put onto other servers to boot them. Should your hard drive actually be damaged, you would just grab a new hard drive, put the image on that you boot on the other servers as well, and replace the one you have in the server.

Comment: Ok thank you so much yes the server on blade servers I will check from iLO management console